# How to handle 15+ useStates in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

ReactJS question:  Essentially I have 20 components that require useState to handle their state to know whether it is okay to show these components.  Each component is based off of A separate value.  I was wondering if it is bad practice or if there is a better way of doing many useState declarations. Instead of having 20 lines of useState.  Thanks. Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just use an object?

Comment: You can also consider `useReducer` if you have complex logic for managing the state https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

Comment: If you have 20 different state variables inside a single component, then stop using a functional component and start using [a class component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) with a normal `this.state` object and state updates using `this.setState(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can store state in an object like this:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
  name: 'John',
  age: 27,
  height: 182
})
```

When you need to update your state you just need to use spreading, this would guarantee you only change the value/s you intended to change while the rest stays the same:

```
setState({
  ...state,
  age: 28
})
```

You can also still make references to your previous state if you need to:

```
setState({
  ...state,
  age: state.age + 1
})
```